# Website assets randomly does not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm sitting here pulling my hair out.. If you visit [my site](http://deangrobler.com/index.html) you are supposed to see something like this:

[image]

The thing is though that sometimes the images load and sometimes they do not. When I run everything from my local machine it works perfectly. But when i upload it to my server the images randomly stop loading sometimes.

I have noticed though that if you're using chrome and you press ctrl + shift + i and the console opens. And you then refresh the page with the console open it then seems to make everything load most of the time.

Comment: I use foundation now for my projects and this shouldn't be the reason. Maybe you should give us an online example. Do you load images with javascript?

Comment: @Reko - I link to the live site in my post, see 'my site'. Otherwise visit deangrobler.com . I don't load them with javascript so to speak but I do make them visible with javascript. Or at least that's what I understand by the plugins I used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the images fail to appear, the problem is not that they aren't loaded by the browser, but that the Freetile plugin is giving the image containers a zero height and width, therefore hiding them.

I think what's happening is your Freetile code is executed before the browser has finished loading the images. I assume Freetile measures the content of the div (which will be zero until the image loaded) and then determines that there is no content and applies the zero height and width.

This explains the inconsistent results because sometimes the browser manages to get the images loaded before Freetile runs, sometimes not.

My theory could be tested by commenting out the Freetile code and add it to a `setTimeout()` call with a long timer such as 5 seconds because you know the images will be fully loaded by then.

Suggested possible fixes:

1. Add the Freetile execution to `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`. The difference is `$(window).load()` only fires when everything is fully loaded (including all images).
2. Add some code that will listen to the images `onload` events and wait until all of them have fired (indicating all images loaded) and then do the Freetile execution. Your use of `$(document).ready()` is not enough because that only means the DOM is loaded and ready, doesn't necessarily mean all images are downloaded and rendered.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I see what you mean and think you're on the right track. I have how ever tried your theory and even went to the extend by completely removing Freetile but the result persisted. 

What I think is happening is that when the HTML loads, the divs 'hover-card' get 0 height and widths because they don't know what they should stretch to since the images in them aren't loaded yet. Could this be a reason as well?

And fixing that would basically mean setting the heights and widths of the 'hover-card' divs before hand.

Comment: It sounds like its the hover card code that is applying the zero height and width then. I would try the same timer test but with hover card delayed instead. Also try the using `$(window).load` for the hover card, or for both if needed.

Comment: Ah nevermind! I put freetile in the window.load and didn't seem to solve the problems straight away. I then put all my other plugins e.g. Jquery box hover and fancybox in window.load as well and that seemed to have fixed the issue :)

Comment: I am wondering though if putting everything in window.load like that is best practice? Because if I have 20+ images, then the user might wait quite some time before the page is displayed correctly..

Comment: If it's just hovercard that needs to go in the window load then I would only put that there. If you have a lot of stuff waiting for the window load then the site could appear slow/sluggish. I wouldn't worry too much about the images, you could look at how fast it is and if it's still too slow an option would be to try and optimise the images to a smaller filesize.

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do is specify the element dimensions as inline CSS styles like so:

`<div class="myElement" style="width:100px; height:200px">Stuff</div>`.

These dimensions will be applied to the element, as such you don't need to wait for images to be loaded.

Additionally, you can add the class `ignore-load-check` to your elements and Freetile will ignore image check for your elements. The [Freetile demo page](http://apex.yconst.com/freetile-demo/freetile.html) offers a demo of this feature.